# SQL Server : Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. Using datediff(year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to compare a normally 4 character string that represents the year someone started in the tax business. I'm trying to create a column called phase for later use.

```
SELECT     dbo.Mentor.UserID, dbo.Mentor.mentee_flag, dbo.Mentor.active, dbo.Mentor.status, 
                      CASE WHEN isnull(Users_Info.Year_started_in_tax, '0') = '0' THEN 1 WHEN isnull(Users_Info.Year_started_in_tax, '0') < '1900' THEN 1 WHEN DATEDIFF(year, 
                      isnull(Users_Info.Year_Started_in_Tax, '0'), GETDATE()) > 29 THEN 5 WHEN DATEDIFF(year, isnull(Users_Info.Year_Started_in_Tax, '0'), GETDATE()) 
                      > 14 THEN 4 WHEN DATEDIFF(year, isnull(Users_Info.Year_Started_in_Tax, '0'), GETDATE()) > 4 THEN 3 WHEN DATEDIFF(year, 
                      isnull(Users_Info.Year_Started_in_Tax, '0'), GETDATE()) > 0 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END AS Phase
FROM         dbo.Mentor INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Users_Info ON dbo.Mentor.UserID = dbo.Users_Info.ID
WHERE     (dbo.Mentor.mentee_flag = 1) AND (dbo.Mentor.active = 1) AND (dbo.Mentor.status = 'True') AND (ISNULL(dbo.Mentor.date_created, cast ('2014/01/01' as datetime)) BETWEEN '2016/02/01' AND '2016/02/24')
```

I'm getting the error on line 2 according to sql studio.  I'm assuming that the problem is coming from the datediff function.

EDIT/Answer:

```
SELECT     dbo.Mentor.UserID, dbo.Mentor.mentee_flag, dbo.Mentor.active, dbo.Mentor.status, ISNULL(dbo.Mentor.date_created, '2014/01/01') AS date_created, 
        CASE WHEN cast(isnull(Users_Info.Year_started_in_tax, '0') as integer) = 0 THEN 1 
        WHEN cast(isnull(Users_Info.Year_started_in_tax, '0') as integer) < 1900 THEN 1 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(year, cast(isnull(Users_Info.Year_Started_in_Tax, 0) as integer), GETDATE()) > 29 THEN 5 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(year, cast(isnull(Users_Info.Year_Started_in_Tax, 0) as integer), GETDATE()) > 14 THEN 4 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(year, cast(isnull(Users_Info.Year_Started_in_Tax, 0) as integer), GETDATE()) > 4 THEN 3 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(year, cast(isnull(Users_Info.Year_Started_in_Tax, 0) as integer), GETDATE()) > 0 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END AS Phase
FROM         dbo.Mentor INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Users_Info ON dbo.Mentor.UserID = dbo.Users_Info.ID
WHERE     (dbo.Mentor.mentee_flag = 1) AND (dbo.Mentor.active = 1) AND (dbo.Mentor.status = 'True') AND (dbo.Mentor.date_created BETWEEN '2016/02/01' AND '2016/02/24')
```

Turns out that casting as an integer did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Strip your SQL back to almost nothing. Start adding back the select parts. At which point does it error?

Comment: Can you show us the structure of your table?

Comment: SELECT     dbo.Mentor.UserID, dbo.Mentor.mentee_flag, dbo.Mentor.active, dbo.Mentor.status, 
                      CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(year, isnull(Users_Info.Year_Started_in_Tax, '0'), GETDATE()) > 29 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END AS Phase
FROM         dbo.Mentor INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Users_Info ON dbo.Mentor.UserID = dbo.Users_Info.ID
WHERE     (dbo.Mentor.mentee_flag = 1) AND (dbo.Mentor.active = 1) AND (dbo.Mentor.status = 'True')

Comment: year_started_in_tax is varchar(4)

Comment: I know this code was working at least a month ago.  My sub conscience might be over reacting.

Comment: Who suggested casting as an integer?  That was the answer.

Comment: I did. But I realised there are other possible ways to do it that are probably better. For example, your current query would work fine if you replaced 0 with `'1900'` in the ISNULL part. Alternatively, replace 0 with `CAST(CAST(0 AS DATETIME) AS DATE)`. Your query is just saying "make it '0' if it's null", which is what it's struggling with. '0' as a varchar(4) doesn't mean anything.

Comment: I think `ISNULL(year_started_in_tax, '1900')` works best because it doesn't require any casts.

Comment: I don't appear to have an option to select the answer.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include it's answer. Instead, answer your own question and mark your answer as accepted. This way people will know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

WHEN DATEDIFF(year, cast(isnull(Users_Info.Year_Started_in_Tax, 0) as integer), GETDATE()) > 29 THEN 5

Casting as an integer did the trick.  Thank you ZLK.